# What files are loaded after modifying the controller file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users_manager engine which has a `User` model class.

In an other shopping engine, I add some associations in the `User` model with the code below, in `shopping/lib/shopping.rb`:

```
module Shopping
  class Engine<Rails::Engine
    initializer :shopping_append_user do
       UsersManager::User.class_eval do
        has_many :products,:class_name=>"Shopping::Product"
        has_many :virtues,:class_name=>"Shopping::Virtue"
        has_many :containers,:class_name=>"Shopping::Container"
        has_many :concerns,:class_name=>"Shopping::Concern"
        has_many :remarks,:class_name=>"Shopping::Remark"
        has_many :praisings,:class_name=>"Shopping::Praising"
        has_one  :cart,:class_name=>"Shopping::Cart"
        has_one  :shop_information,:class_name=>"Shopping::ShopInformation"
        has_many :comments,:class_name=>"Shopping::Comment"
        has_many :created_orders,:class_name=>"Shopping::Order",:foreign_key=>"creator_id"
        has_many :processing_orders,:class_name=>"Shopping::Order",:foreign_key=>"processor_id"
      end
    end

    initializer :shopping_append_file do
      Upload::File.class_eval do
        has_many :image_uuids,:class_name=>"Shopping::ImageUuid"
      end
    end
  end

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "shopping_"
  end
end
```

After running `rails server`, the application works fine. However, after modifying one controller file, I browse the web page and it gives me the following message :

```
undefined method `products' for #<UsersManager::User:0x00000003022a58>
```

How does rails reload the file after modifying them? How can I make my engine work right?

My version of rails is 3.2.0.pre from github, Ruby is 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initializer isn't reloaded on every request, this means that your customizations on the `UsersManager::User` class are lost when it is reloaded.

You can do the following instead:

```
module Shopping
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    config.to_prepare do
      Shopping.customize_user
      Shopping.customize_file
    end
  end

  def self.customize_user
     UsersManager::User.class_eval do
      has_many :products,:class_name=>"Shopping::Product"
      has_many :virtues,:class_name=>"Shopping::Virtue"
      has_many :containers,:class_name=>"Shopping::Container"
      has_many :concerns,:class_name=>"Shopping::Concern"
      has_many :remarks,:class_name=>"Shopping::Remark"
      has_many :praisings,:class_name=>"Shopping::Praising"
      has_one  :cart,:class_name=>"Shopping::Cart"
      has_one  :shop_information,:class_name=>"Shopping::ShopInformation"
      has_many :comments,:class_name=>"Shopping::Comment"
      has_many :created_orders,:class_name=>"Shopping::Order",:foreign_key=>"creator_id"
      has_many :processing_orders,:class_name=>"Shopping::Order",:foreign_key=>"processor_id"
    end
  end

  def self.customize_file
    Upload::File.class_eval do
      has_many :image_uuids,:class_name=>"Shopping::ImageUuid"
    end
  end

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "shopping_"
  end
end
```

The `config.to_prepare` block is run once in production and before every request in development ([source](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2011/01/28/reloading-rails-3-engine-initializers-in-development/)).

Comment: Thanks.In the config.to_prepare  block,self is one instance of ActionDispatch::Reloader.So self.customize_file and self.customize_user can't be called in the confing.to_prepare block.

Comment: @wufengwei thanks for the precision, I updated my answer to reflect this.